# C# Selenium 4 не может получить профиль Firefox, в отличии от старой версии

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Код, позволяющий запускать Firefox с нужным мне профилем:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
var profileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
options.Profile = profileManager.GetProfile("ProfileName");
web = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

прекрасно работал с Selenium 3.141.0. Но мне нужна была возможность открывать новую вкладку, а не окно(способ через Cntrl + t не работает, а другие открывают только окна), которая есть в новой версии Selenium 4 aplha5: `driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab)`

Однако при запуске выскакивает исключение на третьей строчке:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "Cannot find a file named 'X:\A2\PR\C#\WTTB\WTTB\bin\Debug\webdriver_prefs.json' or an embedded resource with the id 'webdriver_preferences.json'."

Что делать? Пробовал найти этот файл, но он похоже существовал только для какой-то древней версии питона.

---

Добавлено: попробовал по аналогии с выбором профиля Chrome в Selenium: `options.AddArguments("-p ProfileName", "-no-remote");` - не помогает(аргументы правильные, с ярлыка нужный профиль запускается).

Явное же указание пути профиля: `options.AddArgument(@"-profile C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\wdeqjtx.AAA");` открывает менеджер профилей(если просто запускать через ярлык - то открывает профиль), в котором я могу выбрать нужный профиль, но в этот момент на 4ой строчке возникает исключение: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: "permission denied"

---

Удалось запустить браузер с нужным профилем на версии 4 alpha1 (на других альфа версиях не вышло). Однако первая альфа настолько сырая, что вообще не работает: программа подвисает на четвертой строчке, и дальше не идет.

Answer (score 0):

```
profil = "C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\wdeqjtx.AAA"

options.AddArguments("-profile", profil, "-no-remote");
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).